# checking and highlighting unsupported special charecters on pasting to a textfield Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here I've a copied text including special characters like `☺■☻♣♦♠☼♫♪↕§` or some other unsupported font characters.

I need to validate this kind of text on pasting to a text field and highlight the place where it is occurred in the pasted text.

I need only the keyboard characters in my text field.How can I do this with Jquery.

Comment: do you want this like grammar checking?

Comment: @PrasanthAR yes something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this jQuery plugin](http://mistic100.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/), hope it helps.

Comment: It Helps. I'll try `$('textarea').highlightTextarea({
  words: ['{(.+?)}']
});` for my requirements.